# Python: Get pywebview Current URL

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using the pywebview library to open a page that will redirect the user to another url. What I would like to do is get the URL the user is directed to.

my code so far:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import webview
import threading
import time

def openwebview():
    time.sleep(1)
    page = webview.create_window("URL_that_redirects_user")

def geturl():
    #what goes here?

t = threading.Thread(target = openwebview)
t.start()
```

I am using Windows, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Author of pywebview here. There is no way to get the current URL. Uou have to dig into an underlying webview to get the URL.
Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into introducing this feature.

Comment: Wow, wasn't expecting a response at this point, let alone from the author of pywebview! I figured out it was impossible but having it as a feature would be really helpful in future projects, thanks!

Comment: The get current url feature is implemented in pywebview 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can do it:

```
def geturl():
    print(webview.get_current_url())
```

See here:
https://github.com/r0x0r/pywebview/blob/master/examples/get_current_url.py